# Cartesian Product Combine 3 List into 1 List of String

Tags: python, python-itertools

I'm trying to combine 3 list into 1 using `itertools`.

```
List1 = A, B,C
List2 = L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,L6,L7
List3 = L1,L2,L3,L4,L5,L6,L7
```

Expected output = `AL1L1,AL1L2,AL1L3,.....`

```
import itertools
def cartesian_product(lists):
    return list(itertools.product(*lists))
ls = [['A', 'B','C'],['L1','L2','L3','L4','L5','L6','L7'],['L1','L2','L3','L4','L5','L6','L7']]
print("Cartesian Product List:",cartesian_product(ls))
```

The output shows:

```
Cartesian Product List: [('A', 'L1', 'L1'), ('A', 'L1', 'L2'),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to s.join it:

```
import itertools
def cartesian_product(lists):
     return list(itertools.product(*lists))
ls = [['A', 'B','C'],['L1','L2','L3','L4','L5','L6','L7'], 
['L1','L2','L3','L4','L5','L6','L7']]
prod_lst = cartesian_product(ls)
s = ""
for i in range(len(prod_lst)):
    prod_lst[i] = s.join(prod_lst[i])
print("Cartesian Product List:",prod_lst)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there - you just need to join the results -

```py
from itertools import product
l1 = list('abc')
l2 = list(f'l{i}' for in range(1, 8))
l2 = list(f'l{i}' for i in range(1, 8))
l3 = list(f'l{i}' for i in range(1, 8))
list(''.join(x) for x in product(l1, l2, l3))
```

**Output**

```
['al1l1',
 'al1l2',
 'al1l3',
 'al1l4',
 ...
]
```